# avoid process to close using python subprocess module

Tags: python

I have a script in python (I called it monitor.py), that checks if another python application (called test.py) is running; if true nothing happens; if false it starts test.py.

I am using the subprocess module in monitor.py, but if I start test.py and I close monitor.py , test.py also closes; is there any way to avoid this ? Is this subprocess module the correct one ?

Comment: See PEP 3134 and [this](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-daemon)

Comment: add the relevant code you are using. There are other probably much easier ways to do what you want like using upstart on linux.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a script [...] that checks if another [...] is running

I'm not sure if it's any help in your case, but i just wanted to say that if you're working with Windows, you can program a real service in python.

Doing that from scratch is some effort, but some good people out there provide examples that you can easily change, like [this one](http://www.chrisumbel.com/article/windows_services_in_python).

*(In this example, look for the line* `f = open('test.dat', 'w+')` *and write your code there)*

It'll behave like any other windows service, so you can make it start when booting your PC, for example.